# Volume integral of current density

Tags: electromagnetism, magnetic-fields, integration, vector-fields, magnetostatics

I'm currently studying magnetostatics and have a simple **question** :

What is the volume integral of the current density over the whole space in magnetostatics $$\int_{V} \textbf{j} \space d^3\textbf{r}$$ in general? Can I just break up the integration into $$\int \textbf{j}\space {dS}\space {dr}=\int0 \space dr =0,$$ since: $$\int_S \textbf{j} =0,$$ if $S$ is a closed surface?

Comment: What if the integral you specify is not zero? Consider the case of a bunch of electrons in a ball that at $t=0$ are allowed to repel. Then you have a case in which charge is flowing outward in all directions, so the current density has nonzero divergence, which by Gauss's Theorem means that there must be a current source inside a sphere surrounding the ball of electrons.

Comment: @probably_someone I don't think the situation given by you is magnetostatic. Magnetostatics involves steady currents and the charge density at any point is constant with respect to time. So by the contunuity equation divergence of current density is 0.

Comment: Oh, yes, sorry. You are indeed correct in magnetostatics. But only because a current source is impossible.

Comment: Just to put this to rest completely, though: consider my situation in the infinite-charge-density limit, after a very long time, so we have an effective equilibrium in the repulsion. Then both the current and the charge density at every point are constant in time.

Comment: @Luka8281 I don't think the volume integral will be 0. For instance take an infinite wire with some constant current and take any volume enclosing part of the wire. Then the surface integral is 0, whereas the volume integral. So I think we can't break up the volume integral like you did.

Comment: The current density is defined as charge per unit cross section $area$. So the integral you must consider is $ \int \textbf{j}\cdot d\textbf{S}  $..Your question is analogous to asking what is the integral of a line charge $ \lambda(x)$ over all of space. $\int \nabla \cdot \textbf{j} d\textbf{V} $ is a volume integral

Comment: @Amara you changed his question itself. The volume integral of current is also a perfectly normal thing to ask about. It is equal to the time derivative of the net dipole moment in the volume.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your main motive is to show that, in magnetostatics, 
$$\int\limits_{V}\mathbf{J}\, d\tau =0 $$
Then there is actually quite a simple way to achieve that, using the fact that, in magnetostatics, 
$$\frac{\partial\rho}{\partial t}=0 $$
We start with the relation, 
$$\int\limits_{V}\mathbf{J}\, d\tau =\frac{d\mathbf{p}}{dt} $$
Where, $\mathbf{p} $ is the electric dipole. Also we know that, 
$$\mathbf{p}=\int\limits_{V}\rho\mathbf{r}\, d\tau $$
Therefore, 
$$\frac{d\mathbf{p}}{dt}=\int\limits_{V}\frac{\partial\rho}{\partial t}\mathbf{r}\, d\tau=0 $$
Which makes, 
$$\int\limits_{V}\mathbf{J}\, d\tau =0 $$